# htaccess redirect for sub dmoain and folder files

Tags: apache, .htaccess

so we had a development site up for example: test.domain.com/dev/filename.html and its been indexed by Google so i need to redirect them to www.newdomain.com/filename.html but not just files but also folders/files like.

test.domain.com/dev/example/filename.html

or
www.newdomain.com/example/example/filename.html

to

www.newdomain.com/filename.html

note that the /dev/ folder on test domain cannot be pushed on the redirect?

Anyone  have any ideas on this?

i have tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !test.domain.co.uk/dev/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

after some tests this redirects to http://www.newdomain.com/dev/page.html and i need to remove the /dev/ .....

and some other options while hunting around but nothing yet meet the requirement.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need RewriteCond so try:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test.domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I tried that but goes to 404 page, maybe because it might be adding /dev/ to the new url as well?

Comment: i just used http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ and still includes /dev/ in the new url but i need to remove this... any ideas?

Comment: You should put the .htaccess file here /dev/.htaccess

Comment: i also get, This rule was not met because one of the conditions was not met when testing the above

Comment: Could it be the RewriteBase / causing an issue?
I have exactly the same as my answer above in place on a site and it works fine. I'm also redirecting from sub.domain.com/dir
Also note that I have used ^test.domain.com NOT !test.domain.co.uk/dev/$

Comment: i took that totally out and used yours, and same 404 on new url but if i go tot the expected url it loads... its strange.... i also remove the htaccess from subdomain root folder as well

Comment: Browsers cache 301 redirects. In some cases deleting the browser cache is not enough to flush this redirect cache. Consider testing in terminal with traceroute or similar or testing with a browser you haven't used for a while